# Timeout Expression in Spring Integration Gateway

Tags: java, spring, timeout, spring-integration

Spring Integration's Gateway element has a "default-reply-timeout" attribute, but no way to set the timeout value based on data from the message itself. I can create a gateway for each possible timeout value and then select an appropriate gateway for that message during run-time, but that's obviously a nasty workaround.

Release 4.2 added a "remote-timeout-expression" attribute to TCPOutboundGateway, but that change didn't make it to the GatewayProxyFactoryBean.

That being said, is there a way to configure timeouts on a message-specific basis? If not, Is the "remote-timeout-expression" attribute planning on being ported to the GatewayProxyFactoryBean at some point?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's currently a fixed value and not configurable on a message-by-message basis.

We can certainly consider making it so but it would likely not make it into 4.3, since [the release candidate is already out](https://spring.io/blog/2016/05/12/spring-integration-4-3-0-release-candidate-available).

One possible work-around would be use `MessagingTemplate`s instead of a gateway. You could set up a collection of `MessagingTemplate`s, each configured with a different timeout, instead of the gateway:

```
 Foo result = this.templateWith10SecondTimeout.convertSendAndReceive(bar, Foo.class);
```

Alternatively, you can add different methods to your gateway, each with a different reply timeout.

```
public interface GW {

     Foo waitTenSeconds(Bar bar);

     Foo waitTwentySeconds(Bar, bar);

}
```

The default timeout is a default, the timeout can be set on each method.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, those workarounds seem like a decent solution for the time being. As far as getting remote-timeout-expression included in the GatewayProxyFactoryBean, is there a feature request I could make for that?

Comment: I already opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4033) if you want to track it.